# Truncate and count positions in Spring with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, aggregation-framework

In my application I want to display a heatmap, so I need something like this to build it:

```
data: [{lat: 24.6408, lng:46.7728, count: 3},{lat: 50.75, lng:-1.55, count: 1}, ...]
```

I have:

```
@Document(collection = "positions")
public class Position {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private long timestamp;
    @GeoSpatialIndexed(type = GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
    private GeoJsonPoint location;
    private File file;
```

In order to count and group the positions that are really near, I thought about truncating all positions and then group them to count. So, for example:

```
{"type" : "Point", "coordinates": [-47.121311,-18.151512]}
{"type" : "Point", "coordinates": [-47.121312,-18.151523]}
{"type" : "Point", "coordinates": [-47.121322,-18.151533]}
```

Result: `{"type" : "Point, "coordinates" : [-47.1213,-18.1515]}, "count" : 3}`

In the shell it would be something like:

```
"$map": {
          "input": '$location.coordinates',
          "in": {
            "$divide": [
              { "$trunc": { "$multiply": [ '$$this', 10000 ] } },
              10000
            ]                
          }
}
```

And then I would group by `location.coordinates`. But I don't know if this is the right approach and also I don't know to to write this code in Spring inside my PositionRepositoryCustom. I would have to create an Aggregation, "do the map" and then the group to count.

Thank you very much.

----EDIT 2---:
I created a class called:

```
public class PositionSummary {

    private List<Double> coordinates;
    private Double count;

    public PositionSummary() { }

    public List<Double> getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(List<Double> coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    public Double getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(Double count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

And my CORRECTED function AggregatePositions() is:

```
@Override
public List<PositionSummary> AggregatePositionss() {

    AggregationOperation project =

            Aggregation.project("location")
                    .and( VariableOperators.mapItemsOf("location.coordinates").
                                    as("coord").
                                    andApply(
                                            ArithmeticOperators.valueOf(
                                                    ArithmeticOperators.valueOf(
                                                            ArithmeticOperators.valueOf(
                                                                    "$$coord"
                                                            ).multiplyBy(1000)
                                                    ).trunc()
                                            ).divideBy(1000)
                                    ))
                                    .as("coordinates");

    AggregationOperation group =
            Aggregation.group("coordinates")
                    .count().as("count");

    Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(project,group);

    //AggregationResults<PositionSummary> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Position.class, PositionSummary.class);

    AggregationResults<PositionSummary> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "positions", PositionSummary.class);

    List<PositionSummary> result = groupResults.getMappedResults();


    return result;
}
```

And I get:

```
[
    {
        "coordinates": null,
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "coordinates": null,
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "coordinates": null,
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "coordinates": null,
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "coordinates": null,
        "count": 2
    },
...]
```

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine. Use the below aggregation code.

```
AggregationOperation project1 = 
         Aggregation.project("type")        
             .and(
                VariableOperators.mapItemsOf("location.coordinates").
                   as("coord").
                   andApply(
                    ArithmeticOperators.valueOf(
                      ArithmeticOperators.valueOf(         
                        ArithmeticOperators.valueOf(
                          "$$coord"
                        ).multiplyBy(1000)
                      ).trunc()
                    ).divideBy(1000)
                  )
             .as("coordinates");

AggregationOperation group = 
         Aggregation.group("coordinates")   
            .first("type").as("type")   
            .count().as("count");

AggregationOperation project2 = Aggregation.project("count","type").andExclude("_id").andInclude(Fields.from(Fields.field("coordinates", "_id")));

Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(project1,group,project2);

List<Document> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg,"positions",Document.class).getMappedResults();
```

Comment: thank you for your response and I appreciate taking your time. I update d my answer with what I did, if you can please check that out, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you try `AggregationResults<PositionSummary> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "positions", PositionSummary.class);` variant  ?

Comment: I changed as you said, but now I get null coordinates. I updated again! Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. That is expected. Updated answer to include the project stage.

Comment: I added the new project stage, and indeed it works now, Thank so much Veeram! I find this topic quite difficult and I didn't found a lot of examples and documentation, so your help was much appreciated.